# SQL query to get AVG from columns and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, average

I have a table like this which consists of several climatic measures (rain rates, temps, etc.)

```
mysql> select rain_rate, temperature, datetime from weather limit 10; 
+--------------+---------------+----------------------+
| rain_rate    | temperature   | datetime             |
+--------------+---------------+----------------------+
| 5.0000000000 | 24.4000000000 | 2017-02-08 16:00:56  |
| 1.0000000000 | 22.4000000000 | 2017-02-06 12:10:36  |
| 2.0000000000 | 28.7000000000 | 2017-02-02 13:57:15  |
| 5.0000000000 | 24.7000000000 | 2017-02-01 14:14:16  |
| 1.0000000000 | 16.1000000000 | 2017-01-08 06:01:26  |
| 2.0000000000 | 18.2000000000 | 2017-01-12 05:10:43  |
| 3.0000000000 | 11.9000000000 | 2017-01-10 06:20:54  |
| 4.0000000000 | 16.8000000000 | 2017-01-25 16:10:14  |
| 5.0000000000 | 24.4000000000 | 2016-12-18 23:10:56  |
| 4.0000000000 | 26.6000000000 | 2016-12-30 09:03:54  |
...
```

As can be seen, timestamps (datetime field) does not follow any pattern.

I want to get the **last 24 average values** of temperature and rain_rate **by hour**, and a column with the numerical value of the associated hour, in 24-hour format, ordered by hour asc.

As an example, if I executed the query today at 18:30 pm, it should return these 24 rows:

```
+-----------------+------------------+-------+
| avg(rain_rate)  | avg(temperature) | hour  |
+-----------------+------------------+-------+
| 3.5000000000    | 23.1000000000    | 19    |  |
| 1.0000000000    | 22.6000000000    | 20    |  |
| 3.5000000000    | 24.7000000000    | 21    |  |-> hours of "yesterday"
| 4.5000000000    | 23.8000000000    | 22    |  |
                    ...
| 2.0000000000    | 26.3000000000    | 13    |  |
| 1.5000000000    | 21.6000000000    | 14    |  |
| 7.0000000000    | 23.4000000000    | 15    |  |-> hours of "today"
| 2.5000000000    | 21.4000000000    | 16    |  | 
| 7.0000000000    | 21.2000000000    | 17    |  |
| 3.0000000000    | 25.3000000000    | 18    |  |
```

My best try so far:

```
select avg(rain_rate), avg(temperature), hour(datetime) as hour
from weather
where (datetime >= now() - interval 24 hour)
group by hour(datetime) 
order by max(datetime) asc
```

It looks like that query returns the correct average values for the fields, but *hour* field does not seem to be ordered like I need nor corresponding to the mean values...

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your query you order by `max(datetime)` instead of `hour(datetime)`

Comment: LIMIT 10, so no ellipsis ;-)

Comment: If I order by *hour(datetime)*, I get always columns from 0 to 23 (hours), which is not what I want...

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also, `LIMIT` is not necessary because group by forces the result to be 24 rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to average by hour for the past 24 hours.

Ok.  Here is one way:

```
select date(datetime), hour(datetime),
       avg(rain_rate), avg(temperature)
from weather 
where (datetime >= now() - interval 24 hour)
group by date(datetime), hour(datetime) 
order by min(datetime);
```

Note:  24 hours from the current time might be a little weird.  You could get 25 rows of records (with two partial hours).  You may want this `where`:

```
where datetime < curdate() + interval hour(now()) hour and
      datetime >= curdate() + interval hour(now()) - 24 hour
```

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . That's reasonable as well.  However, implicit ordering in `group by` has been deprecated since MySQL 5.6.  If you are going to use explicit syntax, might as well use the form consistent across databases.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the `ORDER BY` clause be omitted; I was suggesting that the expressions in the `ORDER BY` be the same expressions used in the `GROUP BY`.  +10. why not just order by the same expressions in the GROUP BY?  (Good catch on the hour boundary; includes rows from 25 distinct hour periods, and grouping the earliest and latest hour into a single row.) And    `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%Y-%m-%d %h') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%Y-%m-%d %h')` would work too.

Comment: Ok, thanks @gordon-linoff. But... How would you update it to get the average in the last week (i.e. 7 days)?

Comment: Yes, @spencer7593, but I mean using the improved `where` version of Gordon's

Comment: Like this: `datetime >= curdate() + interval hour(now)) hour + INTERVAL -7 DAY`.  (That's the same expression used for the end of the range, and then subtract an interval from that.)

Comment: Thanks to both! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you must try `order by datetime`.

The query must be like:

```
select avg(rain_rate), avg(temperature), hour(datetime) as hour
from weather
where (datetime >= now() - interval 24 hour)
group by hour(datetime) 
order by datetime asc;
```

I hope i was help.